# How to adjust the position of absolutely positioned element using jquery?

Tags: jquery

That's what I use as an attempt. The first pieces of adjustment work just fine, which are the visibility and the color. The position just doesn't want to get adjusted.

I tried this

```
$('#feedback_message_signup_final').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#347C17", "position": "absolute", "left":"22.8%"});
```

And this

```
$('#feedback_message_signup_final').css({"visibility": "visible", "color": "#CC0000", "left":"25.8%"});
```

They are different variables but the idea is the same and it won't work in both cases. What's my error?

Answer (score 0):

Typically when I run into problems with positioning (especially after elements have been display:none'd) -- it comes from the initial DOM render doesn't know what the actual width/height/position of that invisible element would be.   This really seems to rear its head on me when I use percentages instead of fixed pixels on these elements.

Can you try it with fixed pixels instead of percentages?